# Vue Js Compiltion Issue with laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am working on an ongoing project and I am unable to recompile assets for vue.js I have deployed the project successfully on my machine with successfully with already compiled assets but when I changed anything the vue and recompile the assets with “npm run dev” or “npm run watch” command it shows me message that build successful but changes are not applied, I want to mention one thing here that in my case “app.js” is replaced with “vue-app.js”.

Comment: Could you please use the edit button and add some full stops to your question. It is currently not very readable. Furthermore we need more information to properly answer your question. You mention `npm run watch`, which I believe is not a default command in Vue CLI 2 or 3. A verbatim error message would be helpful as well. The way you are trying to view your project is also helpful, considering `npm run dev` normally starts a dev server on a port.

Comment: you sure it's not cached in the browser?

Comment: @Sumurai8 fyi: The npm commands are provided by the Laravel boilerplate. The `watch` command does what its saying, while the `dev` command just recompiles the assets to the `public/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to replace `app.js` in `webpack.mix.js` by your new file `vue-app.js`

Comment: vue-app.js is already running but I am unable to recompile this file